# How to split a long order form in Excel into two newspaper-style columns like in Word when printing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a long list 4 columns wide it only takes half the page but is 63 pages long.

I want to arrange it like how Microsoft Word would into two "Columns" not he excel kind columns so that it uses the whole page instead of half.

Arranged side by side. Any help is appreciated.

That is snaking or newspaper style columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: save a tree springs to mind and don't print

Comment: Create a 2 column Word doc, then copy the table in it

Comment: that works......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create a 2-column Word document and copy the Table from Excel into it.

Excel does not have that type of column setup.

(This answer was given by [cybernetic.nomad](https://superuser.com/users/874295/cybernetic-nomad) as a comment.)